# Why isn't $y=\frac{\sin x }{\pi}+x$ invertible

Tags: calculus, functions, inverse-function

Why isn't $\displaystyle y=\frac{\sin x }{\pi}+x$ invertible, i.e. solvable for $x$?

Each $x$ has a unique $y$ so it should be invertible.

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+y%3Dsin(x)%2FPi%2Bx+wrt+x

Comment: There is, theoretically, a solution, but it's not possible (or at least _extremely diffiult_) to write down an explicit expression using a standard toolbox of functions.

Comment: It is invertible (because it is strictly increasing and surjective). Can its inverse function be written in terms of polynomials, square roots, logarithms, trigonometric functions and sections of trigonometric functions? I'd say the answer is "no": it happens quite often.

Comment: Is there a way to work around that? e.g. adding x to two sine waves to make them monotone without the x dissapearing during simplification?

Comment: A continuous monotonic function is guaranteed to be invertible; yet it is not guaranteed that you can express the inverse in terms of elementary functions.

Comment: Ok, thanks everybody!

Comment: Seems like Modular Forms hold the key: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YcmLtktmYyg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Each $x$ has a unique $y$* holds for any function $y=f(x)$, but obviously not every function is invertible. Continuous functions are invertible if monotonic, and 
$$ f(x)=\frac{\sin x}{\pi}+x $$
is an increasing function since
$$ f'(x)= \frac{\cos x}{\pi}+1 > 0.$$